# UICollectionView cell is nil

Tags: swift, null, collectionview

I'm working on a collection view that gets populated with images that I have on Firebase. Everything works fine, but when I try to perform segue I get "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" for this line:

```
if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell){}
```

I have seen many working examples here in SO and apparently they all work fine with that line.

Here is the rest of the relevant code:

```
//grab Firebase objects in viewdidload and put them into productsArray

   var productsArray = [ProductsModel]()

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return productsArray.count
}



override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    //imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    let getUrl = productsArray[indexPath.row].productImg
    imageView.loadUsingCache(getUrl!)

    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0

    return cell
}

    //NAVIGATION
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "itemSegue", sender: nil)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "itemSegue"){

        let destinationController = segue.destination as! ItemViewController

        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell){
            destinationController.getProduct = productsArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I double checked everything is connected and set in the storyboard.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following function, you send the `sender` parameter as `nil`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "itemSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Then in the following function, you receive the `sender` parameter and try to cast it (`sender as! UICollectionViewCell`). This parameter will always be nil.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "itemSegue"){
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! ItemViewController
        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell){
            destinationController.getProduct = productsArray[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want it to be nil, then don't invoke the `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` function with a `nil` `sender`. Send a valid object. In this case, it seems you want `sender` to be of type `UICollectionViewCell`. So send the cell in the `performSegue` function.

*Edit*: Nirav D makes a good point in mentioning that there is no reason to send the cell since it just gets converted back into `indexPath` anyway. We could solve this entire issue by doing:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "itemSegue":, sender: indexPath)
```

and:

```
if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
    destinationController.getProduct = productsArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: No don't send cell as sender, you want indexPath, so simply send the indexPath as sender.

Comment: @Noah1 Nirav makes a good point. Since you are looking for the `indexPath` just send the `indexPath` as `sender` instead of the cell.

Comment: Yeah i figured, still the why it was nil is all I needed. Thanks!